# Sonata User Bundle security roles template override

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, sonata, sonata-user-bundle, symfony-2.8

I am using symphony 2.8 with sonata admin/user/fosuser bundle. Everything is working fine. I just want to override the security roles template because the roles title is not in meaningful. I have followed the below solution.

https://github.com/dianuj89/Sonata-admin-user-friendly-view-for-security-roles

But it's not working I also have done to customization but getting following error.

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\SecurityRolesType::__construct() must be an instance of Sonata\UserBundle\Security\EditableRolesBuilder, none given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\energyvalue\vendor\sonata-project\core-bundle\Form\Extension\DependencyInjectionExtension.php on line 94 and defined

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to provide translation messages for the role names.

```
#Resources/translations/messages.en.yml

ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN: 'My custom label'
```

Comment: It's working fine thanks. But i also want to group the roles module wise. Right now it displaying long list of roles.is there any way to do that.